# Complex financial calculations/business rules in Angular

Tags: c#, angularjs, web-services, soa, business-logic

I am looking at developing a SPA application probably with Angular.

One of the challenges we face is that we have considerable amount of financial based calculations that comes into play whilst the user is entering values on a form.  Here’s a simplified example:

> The user is entering a detail line on a sales transaction entry form.
>   As they enter the Net amount, the system should calculate the Sales
>   Tax amount and Gross value based on the net value entered (as I say,
>   it does get more complex than this).
>   **The important thing to note here, is that as the user tabs out of the Net field, they should see the Tax and Gross fields update.**

So I see two high level options here:

1. Either code this calculation in JavaScript
2. Make a service call to
   perform the calculation

Either way, I want the Angular style model to be updated with the result of the calculation which will cause the view to update.

Where possible, I would prefer to do this through a service call, as that way it opens the door to re-using this logic from other clients in the future.  I also think that coding this sort of logic in C# should be faster to develop and more maintainable (and keeps the logic in one place).

Ideally I would like this logic in the C# entity in the service that models the transaction.

How should I therefore go about calling such server side logic?

1. Should I somehow pass the whole client side representation of the
   model back up to the service and have it calculate the other values?
   Not sure how I would do this in terms of telling the service which
   values actually need calculating.
2. Or should I have (lots of) individual
   service methods named things like CalculateTax(net, taxPercentage)
   that returns the Tax amount.

Or is there some other method or pattern that I am missing altogether here?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would create an API endpoint that received the calculation you needed and the values, and would return the result. This would be the same as getting a single record from a normal CRUD API making your angular service quite simple:

```
angular.module('fin',[]).service('calculation', function($http) {
    return {
        getResult: function(calcMethod, values){
             return $http({
                url: 'http://backend.com/calculate',
                method: 'GET',
                params: {
                    calcMethod: calcMethod,
                    values: values
                }
             });
        }
    }
}
```

And then you could just call from your controller, something like this:

```
Service.getResult('Sales Tax',[$scope.value1, $scope.value2]).success( function(res) {
    $scope.result = res;
});
```

Comment: So you are suggesting a single endpoint, that takes in a parameter which specifies the calculation type i.e. CalcTax, CalcCurrencyTax etc.?  Then performs the applicable calculation - that certainly seems worth considering.

Comment: The other issue I face is where in the service I actually do that calculation?  For example, I would like it the SalesTransaction entity, so that on the property set of the net amount, it does the calculation.  So I suppose in this service method, I could create a new instance of the SalesTransaction, set the Net and tax rate say, and then read and return the calculated values.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but I would just do it as part of the controller and wouldn't store any of the calculated values in your entity. You only want to submit back to your server the SalesTransaction with the user inputs, and you'll need to recalculate the other values again on the server side, since a user could modify your js object on the client side.

Comment: In terms of the client, the user can, in some situations, change the calculated Tax amount, so it needs to be a property on the model.  My last point was more about how I write the code service side, to do the calculation.  For example, do I just have code in the service method to do this.  Or do I try and place that logic in the server side entity/model (even though at the time of doing this calculation I wont be saving it to the database).

Comment: From what I can tell you have two ways of doing it. Either the service is stupid and just gets a value from the server, therefore it doesn't need to calculate it. Or the server replies with a formula (a bit weird since you'd have to store a javascript formula on the DB, although it might work quite well) and then the service applies that formula, to whatever parameters you have.

Comment: Maybe I'm confusing things with my comments here - my high level option 2 above, is all about having C# code, somewhere in the service (so .NET server side code) to perform the calculation.  So from my controller, I call the service to perform the calculation.  If I was to perform the calculation in JavaScript I would just have that logic in the Angular controller.

Comment: When I mentioned service, I was referring to an Angular Service. On the server side you could have a Dictionary of lambda expressions or just have a switch case statement with all your calculations, which is essentially your option 2. Don't know a better/different way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

With all my love to javascript, I would never trust financial calculation to it, especially on client side.

But. It depends on what exactly you need to calculte. I mean:

1) (your case) Server gives you "source" values(like user's amount etc.) and percentage(or user enters it), AND you don't pass this data to server, then you definitely can, and I think should, do this on client side.

2) If you have smth like price and amount of items, you should calculate it on server(you can do pre-calculation on UI), but confirm it from server too.

Answer (score 0):

Now according to the business scenario you have provided, it seems the calculations are such that you would not want others to know, how its done. The calculations are best kept in the server side
When ever you tab out of the field of the net amount, you can call the server to fetch you the sales tax and the other values you calculate.

You can go through  like this.

You have the methods to calculate the sales tax. Now this needs a net amount. So when ever you enter the net amount and you tab out of the field you can call the individual service to get the sales tax amount and the gross amount. Here your input to the service is not the whole client side but just the net amount that is bounded to the controller.

Comment: Good point on the calcs in the JavaScript and keeping it private - another reason to make the service call and have this logic server side.